# If Search Field Cell is Blank use Wildcard

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, excel-2010, wildcard

I'm trying to setup a dynamic search in Excel. I have this:

```
 Column A    |        Column B
Match Type   | "Search term goes here."
     Class   | "Search term goes here."

Total Wins   | "Search results."
Total Losses | "Search results."
```

So far the code I use works.

`=(COUNTIFS(Match Stats'!F:F,B1,Match Stats'!J:J,B2))`

The user types the criteria where it says `Search term goes here.` and the 
`Search results.` cells are populated correctly.

However, I want the code to put in an asterisk `*` (which is the Excel wildcard) when one of or both of the `Search term goes here.` boxes are left blank, this way the user does not have to manually type the *asterisk* in the *search terms* if they do not wish to filter that particular search criteria.

**How do I go about this?**

**Note:** The code I showed is only a portion of it, but for this question it is the only portion I am concerned with and should be enough to suffice for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having `B1` in the countifs, use anIF statement that tests and produces the result you expect.

```
IF(LEN(B1)=0,"*",B1)
```

(I use LEN, as this will return the same result if there is an empty string, or an empty cell - you could use `TRIM` to test for spaces used to empty the cell)

This will make your count formula, with the same test for B2

```
=(COUNTIFS(Match Stats'!F:F,IF(LEN(B1)=0,"*",B1),Match Stats'!J:J,IF(LEN(B2)=0,"*",B2)))
```